# How do you upload xlsx files to the SSRS Server progamatically?

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

I've got a large amount of Excel xlsx files I want to upload to my SSRS server.  Going through the web UI I can only do one at a time.  Can I user Powershell or something to upload all of them?  SQL Server 2019.  Thanks!

Comment: If you mean going thru an ETL-like process, sure. However, Remember SSO rules are: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). What did you search for and try?

Comment: No, I don't mean going through an ETL-like process.  Have you ever worked with SSRS? If not then you won't understand the question.